# Hibernate warning about follow-on locking using Oracle 10g

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, warnings, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate 4.3.0.Final / JPA 2.1, Hibernate Search 4.5.0.Final running on WildFly 8.0.0.Final. **My application works absolutely fine**, but I am getting this hibernate warning when the indexes are being created.

> WARN org.hibernate.loader.Loader - HHH000444: Encountered request for locking however dialect reports that database prefers locking be done in a separate select (follow-on locking); results will be locked after initial query execute

This is the method that creates the index:

```
public void createIndex() throws DAOException {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

    try {
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer(Colaborador.class)
            .purgeAllOnStart(Boolean.TRUE)
            .optimizeOnFinish(Boolean.TRUE)
            .startAndWait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Error creating index", e);
            throw new DAOException(e);
    }
}
```

I've done some searches and I found a "solution" or, better saying, **a way to suppress the warning**. However, I don't know if this is the best solution. The solution proposes to extend the `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` and override the method `public boolean useFollowOnLocking()` to return `false`.

Other important thing: this only happens after Hibernate version 4.2.0.Final. Before this version, there isn't a `useFollowOnLocking()` method.

The new dialect:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect;

public class MyOracle10gDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {

    @Override
    public boolean useFollowOnLocking() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I found this solution **[here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=992697&view=next)** and **[here](http://reach2ramesh.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/hibernate-usefollowonlocking-warning.html)**. There is also a **[bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8135)** that was reject about this warning. I've not found any other solution available for this warning.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no reason to worry about this warning, logging it was a mistake: you should ignore it, or change the logger configuration to ignore it.

I've opened [HHH-9097](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9097).